# dotnet run command does not find user secrets

Tags: asp.net, .net, asp.net-core

I have a asp.net core project running on a macbook. I'm using visual studio code as my code editor. When I run the project from visual studio code the application boots fine however when I execute `dotnet run` from the terminal in the project's working directory I get an error that the database hostname value is null. This value is defined in `user-secrets`. Is there an extra setup I'm missing from the command line?

Comment: Is it loading the user secrets only in Development as is normally done? If so, you have to remember to set the environment variable ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT to Development.

Comment: You should post this an an answer. It's correct and I will accept it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If it is loading the user secrets only in Development as is normally done, you have to remember to set the environment variable ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT to Development.